# How to update existing filtered elasticsearch query in .net nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I've a json query coming from gui. It has filtered query parts in it. I want to extend filtered query with date range filter How can I do that using nest. I tried a method (QueryTest method) like below, but failed.

```
public SearchDescriptor<dynamic> GetSearchDescriptor(string queryJson = null)
    {
        var searchDesc = new SearchDescriptor<dynamic>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryJson))
        {
            return searchDesc;
        }

        searchDesc = _nestClient.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchDescriptor<dynamic>>(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryJson)));

        return searchDesc;
    }

public string ConvertToJsonQuery(SearchDescriptor<dynamic> searchDescriptor)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_nestClient.Serializer.Serialize(searchDescriptor, SerializationFormatting.Indented));
    }

public void QueryTest()
    {
        var query = @"{     
                        ""query"": {
                        ""filtered"": {
                            ""filter"": {
                            ""bool"": {
                                ""must"": [
                                {
                                    ""term"": {
                                    ""display_name"": ""NBLEYLEK$""
                                    }
                                }
                                ]
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }";

        var searchDescriptor = GetSearchDescriptor(query).AllTypes(); 

        var queryLastA = ConvertToJsonQuery(searchDescriptor);

        searchDescriptor.Query(x => x.Filtered(y => y.Filter(z => z.Range(t => t.OnField("sign_time").Greater(DateTime.Now)))));

        var queryLastB = ConvertToJsonQuery(searchDescriptor);
    }
```

If I look at values of queryLastA and queryLastB, I see as:

**queryLastA =>**

```
{      
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "display_name": "NBLEYLEK$"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**queryLastB =>**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "sign_time": {
            "gt": "2015-08-25T16:13:56.694"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***The desired query is :***

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "display_name": "NBLEYLEK$"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "sign_time": {
                  "gt": "2015-08-25T16:13:56.694"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect from nest to append new filter under old one, but it ignores old filter (compare queryLastB with queryLastA). Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in nest if we give new filter, it overrides the old filter. I had the same problem. I did string operations on query and converted it into c# class and applied filter from scratch using nest. This worked out for me.

Comment: I have similar problem, do you have any updated approach on this @Ravindra Kumar Challagandla